# Display sublayers in group layer

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I would like to expand sublayers when the map starts.

I set sublayers and expanded to true but do not see changes.

I wonder if I misplaced or used the incorrect code.

```
        layerControl: {
            include: true,
            id: 'layerControl',
            type: 'titlePane',
            path: 'gis/dijit/LayerControl',
            title: i18n.viewer.widgets.layerControl,
            iconClass: 'fa-th-list',
            open: true,
            position: 0,
            options: {
                map: true,
                layerControlLayerInfos: true,
                separated: false,
                vectorReorder: false,
                overlayReorder: false,
                sublayers: true,
                expanded: true,
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

`sublayers` and `expanded` are specific to each layer not the widget. These options should be placed within the `layerControlLayerInfos` for the layer. Here's an [example](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/blob/develop/viewer/js/config/viewer.js#L263). These and other options for the layerControlLayerInfos are listed in the [CMV documentation](http://docs.cmv.io/en/latest/widgets/LayerControl/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I realized expanded works one level. Would it be possible to expand deeper sublayers?

Comment: You can expand group layers in the TOC within the MXD used for the Map Service. There is currently no way to do that within the CMV configuration.